# How to find Azue Ultra disks IOPS and Disk throughput range based on disk Size, using azure API

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template, azure-disk

I need to know Azue Ultra disks IOPS and Disk throughput range based on disk Size, using azure API, I need help on if any document is available to understand it.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? if you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we can use the following Azure rest API to get the key capabilities of ultra disks.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriotion ID>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?$filter=location eq '<the location you want to check>'  &api-version=2019-04-01
```

For instance, if you want to check southeast Asia, you will get a list as below, which contains ultra disk info :
[image]

Then we can use these capabilities to know IOPS and Disk throughput range based on disk Size. For example, The minimum IOPS per disk is 2 IOPS/GiB and the max IOPS per disk is 300 IOPS/GiB. Meanwhile, The IOPS disk should be greater than 100 IOPS and less than 160000 IOPS. So if our disk zise is 4 GB, the IOPS range is 100 - 1200.  For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-types#ultra-disk).